# Core Data-GROUP BY using an attribute of another entity which is forms a relationship with my entity

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by

Suppose I have 2 entities in Core Data as follows:-

Entity Employee:

> Attributes of Employee:- name, designation, salary, department

Entity Department

> Attributes of Department:- name, departmentRank

Here is the department property of Employee is actually a relationship to an element of type Department. It can be assumed to be a one-to-one relationship for now.

What I want to do is to run a GROUP BY query on entity Employee with the departmentRank attribute of the department property. i.e I want to group by rows of Employee using department.departmentRank

Is this possible? Some code or reference to some article would really be appreciated.

Comment: You want to display a list of employee ordered by departmentRank?

Comment: I want to display groups of employees  with the grouping criteria being departmentRank.